# How to migrate componentWillReceiveProps in react 16.0.0?

Tags: reactjs

I have a reactcomponent that has a few obsolete events:

```
componentWillMount() {
    const { applicationStages } = this.props;
    if (applicationStages && applicationStages.length > 0) {
        this.setState({
            appColumnsSorted: this.getSortedAppColumns(someVar),
        });
    }
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const {
        presets: { sortCriteria: sortBy, customCriteria },
    } = nextProps;
    const { appColumnsSorted } = this.state;
    const sortedColumnsUpdated = this.getSortedAppColumns(
        appColumnsSorted,
        sortBy,
        true
    );
    this.setState({
        appColumnsSorted: sortedColumnsUpdated,
    });
}

getSortedAppColumns = (appColumns, sortBy, criticalFirst) => {
   //returns object
};
```

'componentWillMount' is basically to initialize the appColumnsSorted. The issue is that with v16 this event is obsolete. So what can event can I use for this now? Also what is the way to migrate 'componentWillReceiveProps' in this scenario?

Comment: these aren't "events" they are lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're using componentWillMount for can be done in the constructor so

```
componentWillMount() {
    const { applicationStages } = this.props;
    if (applicationStages && applicationStages.length > 0) {
        this.setState({
            appColumnsSorted: this.getSortedAppColumns(someVar),
        });
    }
}
```

will change to

```
export default class YourClass extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
        // keep a separate method just to avoid writing code in constructor for readability
        this.state = constructInitialState(props);
   }

   constructInitialState(props) {
       const state={};
       //More state handling as required
       const { applicationStages } = props;
       if (applicationStages && applicationStages.length > 0) {
           state.appColumnsSorted = this.getSortedAppColumns(someVar);
       }
       return state;
   }
}
```

This approach is slightly better because getDerivedStateFromProps will be called before each render and will waste computation.

From the code snippet it is not obvious why you want to store it in state. If you do save it to state then the only way you have would be to use componentDidUpdate as mentioned in the other answer by Aaditya Thakkar. This will require you to mirror your props in state only for comparison purpose (Mapping props to state is not the best way, more on this link https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#anti-pattern-unconditionally-copying-props-to-state)

I would, however, recommend calling your sort computation method and return its result in render directly; this would avoid extra checks in componentDidUpdate to render the second time. As I'm not aware if these props are coming from redux or a parent React component, another option would be to avoid expensive computation in this class and simply provide the correct value from either the parent component or calculate the value in the redux store and send the final prop directly for use.

Comment: Thought you cannnot setstate on a component that is not mounted yet?

Comment: In constructInitialState you are returning an object which will be assigned to this.state. setState is not used in the constructor.

Comment: and what todo like the question said abt the componentWillReceiveProps?

Comment: As i said since i don't have the complete context of the parent or the reducer that passes these props, i have given three options
1) Call the sort computation in render directly and use its value in the render method. Downside of this is that if your computation is very expensive and if your component re renders then it will be recomputed whether or not the original prop changed.
2) Make the computation in the parent or in the redux action and pass the final prop to your child. You can always use a utility function if this computation is done from multiple places.

Comment: 3) use componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) as mentioned in the other answer by doing 
if (prevProps.unchangendProp !== this.props.unchangedProp) { /*Your code*/ }. No need to save state, simply compare the current and previous props. Note that the unchangedProp is a value that will only change when the props actually change, this will prevent componentDidUpdate from firing twice.

Answer (score 0):

ComponentWillReceiveProps can be replaced with `getDerivedStateFromProps`. `getDerivedStateFromProps` is invoked right before calling the render method, both on the initial mount and on subsequent updates. It should return an object to update the state. It's a static method, so `this` can not be used inside it.

Hence, you can no longer reference `this.getSortedAppColumns` from getDerivedStateToProps, you need componentDidUpdate lifecycle for that. Here, I have broken down `ComponentWillReceiveProps` into `getDerivedStateFromProps` and `componentDidUpdate`:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  const {
    presets: { sortCriteria: sortBy },
  } = nextProps;
  if (sortBy === prevState.sortBy) return null;
  return ({ sortBy: nextProps.sortBy });
}

componentDidUpdate(_, prevState) {
  const { appColumnsSorted, sortBy } = this.state;
  if (sortBy !== prevState.sortBy) {
    const sortedColumnsUpdated = this.getSortedAppColumns(
      appColumnsSorted,
      sortBy,
      true
    );
    this.setState({
      appColumnsSorted: sortedColumnsUpdated,
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you make sure the state is not set in the 'getDerivedStateFromProps' method when componentWillMount is firing?

Comment: since you are using 'componentWillMount' to initialize the appColumnsSorted, you can do that in `componentDidMount` or you can initialize it in the constructor itself.  Now about second thing, to make sure the state is not set in the `getDerivedStateFromProps`, you can put a check there since you have `prevState` available. `If (!prevState.appColumnsSorted) return null;`. state will not update if you return null from getDerivedStateFromProps